# C# Multithreading issue when loading data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

I have a list of about 7030 items. I save the items from the list to a table in SQL server. I thought, I could use multithreading to speed up the process, which it did, however, there emerged an issue.

The number of items being uploaded to the database does not change, but when I query the number of records in the table after running my code, its always different, say one time it will have uploaded 6925, next time 6831 etc. I cannot see why this is happening.

**In the class where I get the data**

```
 void DatabaseUploadMultiThreading()
    {
        DateTime dtUpload = Program.UploadDate();

        int numThread = 8;          
        int splitNum = _holdingList.Count / numThread;
        int leftOver = _holdingList.Count - (splitNum * (numThread - 1));

        DatabaseWriter[] dbArray = new DatabaseWriter[numThread];
        List<Holding>[] holdingArray = new List<Holding>[numThread];
        Task[] taskDB = new Task[numThread];

        for (int i = 0; i < holdingArray.Length; i++)
        {
            dbArray[i] = new DatabaseWriter(i + 1, dtUpload);

            if (i == (numThread - 1))
                holdingArray[i] = _holdingList.GetRange(i * splitNum, leftOver);
            else
                holdingArray[i] = _holdingList.GetRange(i * splitNum, splitNum);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < taskDB.Length; i++)
            taskDB[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(dbArray[i].UploadHoldings, holdingArray[i]);

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(taskDB);                   // wait for all the threads to complete
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
        }

    }
```

**The DatabaseWriter class snipet**

```
 class DatabaseWriter : IDisposable
{
    #region variable declaration
    private SqlConnection _connection;
    private SqlCommand _command;
    private static readonly string _connectionString = "myConnectionString";

    public void UploadHoldings(object objHoldingList)
    {
        List<Holding> holdingList = (List<Holding>)objHoldingList;

        using (_connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            _connection.Open();

            DataReImported(_dtUpload);

            for (int i = 0; i < holdingList.Count; i++)
            {
                string cmdText = "INSERT INTO HOLDINGS([FUND_CD], [SEDOLCHK], [NOMINAL], [CURR], [PRICE], [DATEU]) " +
                                    "VALUES(@fundcode, @sedol, @nominal, @curr, @price, @dtUpload)";

                _command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, _connection);
                _command.Parameters.Add("@fundCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = holdingList[i].FundCode;
                _command.Parameters.Add("@sedol", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = holdingList[i].IdSedol;
                _command.Parameters.Add("@nominal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = holdingList[i].Nominal;
                _command.Parameters.Add("@curr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = holdingList[i].Currency;
                _command.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = holdingList[i].Price;
                _command.Parameters.Add("@dtUpload", SqlDbType.Date).Value = _dtUpload;
                _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Thread Number:" + _threadNum + " Security Number uploaded: " + i + " of " + holdingList.Count);
            }
            _connection.Close();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Have you considered doing a [Bulk Insert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)? Just write all the data to a temp file that the server can reach and import.

Comment: Does the ExecuteNonQuery ever returns 0? if so, these are your missing values in database.

Comment: Since you're trying to optimize, have you considered constructing `SqlCommand` and its params once, and then simply updating values on each execution, rather than rebuilding entire `SqlCommand` hierarchy for each record?

Comment: If your use SQL Server 2008 or greater you can use table-valued parameters. It will be mach faster.

Comment: Also, have you considered inserting more than one record per execution? E.g. `INSERT INTO tbl(fn1, fn2) VALUES (f11, f12), (f21, f22), ...`.  See [Table Value Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: @GabrielGM just went through the code and ExecuteNonQuery never returns zero

Comment: If you where to run this code again, on the same thread, as opposed to creating a new one, does the number of rows of data submitted change. I personally don't think this issue has anything to do with the fact your running in in a separate task.

Comment: Also, As tasks can return a value Task<T> why not record the result of each task that you run,  the number of threads executed.

Comment: @Derek yes when I run it on a single thread I get the correct output everytime. That's a good idea about checking the value of a Task, let me try that

Comment: @Derek I used the Task.Status property (not sure if this is exactly what you meant) and for all 8 threads it said RanToCompletion. Looking in SQL Server can see that about 80 records are missing though. On the console for each thread it writes row i out of 800 (example) uploaded & I see all threads report 800 out of 800 uploaded. Seems to be uploading all the rows but obviously not.

Comment: No, What i meant, is that Task<T> allows you to return a result of any type of object you want. In your UploadHoldings(object objHoldingList) method, you should put in a try/Catch block and where any exceptions might be caught, you can return and int value of o, where no exception is found it returns 1 back to the thread (Task) object that started it. If that makes any sense.  Your code would be Task<int>[] taskDB = new Task[numThread]; each task returns an integer. It might help, sorry i havent more time to explain this.

Comment: @Derek, that's fine. I put a try catch block around the _command.ExecuteNonQuery and stored the results in an int[]. None of the threads had any exceptions when executing. A different number of rows again was return when looking in sql server

Comment: Well - if the numbers imported vary, then you have some access to a shared resource which aren't synchronized and thus generating a race condition when trying to write it to the database. My advice is to start smaller. Wrap your entire UploadHoldings as a static and take all it need as input paramaters to avoid mixing non-thread safe variables/object references with threads. Then I'd do a parallel.foreach instead of task and make sure that parallel similar does not mix class-member variables with the threading. From there you can then expand.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that this, is not an optimal place to use multiple Tasks. Your code as shown above is a little inefficient, and splitting it into Task objects and running them in parallel, in many cases only serves to make them stumble over top of one another and slows you down or causes one of them to not execute. Like when the Three Stooges all try to rush into a door at the same time.

Do the basic, obvious optimizations as the other answerers have suggested above, ie create your SqlCommand only once, and do an absolute minimum within the loop (or, try a bulk-loading method). And check the value returned by ExecuteNonQuery to verify the number of records written.